# Is there any way to get value from the previous class?

Tags: php, class

```
<?php  

class A { 
  var $varA; 

  function funcA() { 
        $this->varA='AAAA'; 
        $bbb = new B(); 
        $bbb->funcB();
  } 
}

class B {         
    function funcB() { 
        //### Is there any way to get value of $varA from here?
    } 
} 

echo $aaa->funcA;  

?>
```

Please see the code above. Is there any way to get value of $varA from funcB()? I know about global and I know I can pass it or add var $varB; to the B class and set it. I am asking is there any standard way (syntax) to just get the value?

Answer (score 0):

You could make the variable in class A public and static, which would make it accessible using `A::$varA`.

```
class A {
  public static $varA;

  function funcA() {
        self::$varA = 'AAAA';
        $bbb = new B();
        $bbb->funcB();
  }
}

class B {
    function funcB() {
        // Get value of $varA from A statically
        echo A::$varA;
    }
}
```

However, I wouldn't recommend doing it this way, as order of operations becomes more important.  I'd look at traditional public getters/setters and take a look at possible desing flaws leading you to needing this solution in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Making it static is approximately the same as making it global $varA; outside of the class. 

I know about design flaws. It's not my code and right now the $varA is just passed to funcB($varA). Since funcB($varA) is called many times (with different parameters) and $varA is actually a huge array, I am looking for something more optimized.